# Sum space-separated integers as string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have this list: `['5 4 7', '4 3 1', '6 8 4'', '4 8 6']`
Note that not all numbers are separated by commas.

I would like to be able to calculate the total for each section of the list. For example, the first calculation should be 5+4+7 to give me 16. I would just like to know how to convert this list to be able to do maths calculations with the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

split your strings, map to integer and perform `sum` on the resulting inputs, in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(map(int,x.split())) for x in ['5 4 7', '4 3 1', '6 8 4', '4 8 6']]
[16, 8, 18, 18]
```

(works for negative values as well :))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex:

```
import re
s = ['5 4 7', '4 3 1', '6 8 4', '4 8 6']
new_s = [sum(map(int, re.findall('\d+', b))) for b in s]
```

Output:

```
[16, 8, 18, 18]
```

However, if every digit is a single character, then you can use `isdigit()`:

```
last_result = [sum(map(int, filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(), i))) for i in s]
```